# configure jshint enabled (and other options) as defaults for each new project

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm

Is there any way to configure jshint options (and possibly some other options) to be applied for each new project? Currently I have jshint enabled for my project, but when I create another project its not enabled there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**File | Default Settings** -- settings available there will be applied to all future new projects (created on this computer).

In PhpStorm v8.0.2 / WebStorm v9 -- look for special symbols:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I knew that it would be you to answer the question :). You're a Jetbrains expert around here. What do you mean by this _In PhpStorm v8.0.2 / WebStorm v9 -- look for special symbols:_ ?

Comment: IDEs built on 139.xxx branch have new restructured Settings screen (IDE-wide and Project-specific settings merged together -- there is no "sub-sections" any more). Settings that are applicable to current or default project will have special "marks" -- just as highlighted by red line on the screenshot. If settings page does not have such symbol/text then it's an IDE-wide setting.

Comment: Thanks, got it. I'm still using old versions though.